# Compare data and add send email action using rules module

Tags: rules

I have two content types:

- "Reserve a trip" with the fields Res_Date_Between, and Res_date_and
- "Post a trip" with the fields Post_Date_Between, and Post_date_and

The users who organize the trip and who have the permission to add the content type *Post a trip*, can give the trip the departure date (Post_Date_Between) and the end date (Post_date_and). The users who want to reserve the trip have the permission to add the content type "Reserve a trip", and can give the trip the departure date (Res_Date_Between) and the end date (Res_date_and).

What I need is verifying the "add new content type" event occurred for the "Post a trip" content type, and add the "send email" action for the users who reserve a trip checking that the dates in the the two fields of the "Reserve a trip" content type are within the two dates of the "Post a trip" content type.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: tnks @Klamlaluno

Comment: you can achieve it using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module

Comment: @Aboodred1 yes i know , i need any lessons or something like that can help me with what  i need , tnks ^^